# Android Emulator with non-standard Screen Resolution

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried make an emulator with 480x480 pixels square resolution. But the emulator never finishes starting. It gets stuck on the Android logo page. Is there a restriction for the resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

The emulator

> is not smart about screen size
>   however, and may be too large for some
>   monitors. If you have this problem,
>   start the emulator instead using "SDK
>   setup" program from the main Android
>   SDK directory before you run a
>   program. It will give you a dialog to
>   set the size or scale. Setting the
>   height to 8" works well on 768-pixel
>   high monitors.

You should check out this wiki site by UC Berkeley. Does a great job explaining and walking one through to setting up Android dev for Windows, Macs, etc. but only on Eclipse FYI. The above snippet is the last paragraph in the first section "Android Quickstart":

http://bid.berkeley.edu/cs160-fall10/index.php/Tips_and_Tricks

Answer (score 0):

You could do a little hack to achieve smaller screen resolution to grab a feel of it. The solution is to append the parameter -scale  to the Emulator launch parameters. In eclipse, put it in the field "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" within the Run Configuration.
Or turn on your command line and use: emulator -avd "Your Device" -scale [number] OR emulator -avd "Your Device" -skin 480x480
Good luck^^